# Small electronic project kit

Tags: transistors, led, circuit-analysis, pcb, schematics

I ordered this electronics project kit which consists of a small PCB. You have to solder the components onto the board.

[image]

The components are:

- Two 510 ohm resistors (green, brown, brown)
- Two 33k ohm resistors (orange, orange, orange)
- Two transistors
- Two electrolytic capacitors
- Two LEDs
- Power leads red to VCC and black to ground.

After assembling the circuit here is my result. The two LEDs light up.

[image]

[image]

The booklet does not state what the circuit is supposed to do.

Is two lit up LEDs all that the circuit is supposed to produce?

What would the schematic look for like this circuit?

Comment: Welcome! Please show a picture of the back of the board.

Comment: the circuit works a lot better with light bulbs than LEDs. maybe you can figure out why as a learning exercise.

Comment: @dandavis the board was designed with LEDs in mind based on the silk screen

Comment: I have showed a picture of the back of the board

Comment: It looks like you have a short circuit between the third pad from the top right and the one just below it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's almost certainly an **astable multivibrator**, or LED flashing circuit, which is a classical circuit and one which is often a first project.

Here's a tutorial on one.

https://www.build-electronic-circuits.com/astable-multivibrator/

Try following the tracks on the bottom of the PCB and see if you can match it to the diagram in the tutorial I linked.

Comment: Okay thanks. Yes I was sure it had to flash because of the capacitors.

Answer (score 3):

It is supposed to flash the LEDs alternately.

Here is a likely schematic using similar part types and values. I've made it a bit asymmetric by changing R1/R2 by +/-10% from nominal (and skipped initial condition) so it will start reliably.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fZjSDy.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Below is a simulation in the Circuit lab functionality of SE showing the LED currents vs. time, blue being the left LED D1 and orange being the right LED D2. 
The timing is controlled by the time constants R1*C1 and R2*C2.

[image]

In your real circuit if you bring up the power supply voltage slowly enough (for example, using a lab supply and turning the knob up slowly) the astable multivibrator will not start and both LEDs will remain on. So switch it on quickly.

Note that 9V as shown is a bit hard on the transistors since it exceeds the absolute maximum Vebo specification for the 9014. Breaking down the E-B junction can cause long term damage to the transistors (lowered hFE). 5V is 100% safe for this type of transistor and 6V is almost always safe (for jellybean silicon transistors).

Comment: I have shown the back of the circuit board and I have soldered the components based on the tutorial. However the LED’s do not blink alternately.

Comment: What have I done wrong ? Is it the soldering ? Or are the tracks on the circuit board created wrong ?

Comment: If you post clear well-lit photos of both sides of the board we may be able to help with that. Also confirm that you're switching the supply on without a gentle increase.

Comment: Q1 emitter appears to not be soldered. There might be other things. Cleaning it with 99% isopropyl alcohol would help see what is going on.